# When to use record struct instead of struct, and vice versa?

Tags: c#, struct, c#-9.0, c#-10.0, c#-record-type

I have found out recently about the `record` keyword in C#, and saw that it can be used as `record struct` in a way to make it, if I understood correctly, a value type instead of a reference type.

However, I'm having a hard time to understand when exactly to use `record struct` instead of just the `struct`. From what I saw, the `record struct` has some base implementations that the struct doesn't (like the `==` and `!=` operators, an override of the `ToString`, and some other things), but is it all that is there for difference between the two? If not, what needs to be considered when deciding to use one or another?

From the way I currently see, it might be better to always use the `record struct` just to take advantage of those implementations that already comes with it.

Comment: This comes down to the question of using structs vs classes, the "record" thing is just lateral in this question.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues the question is not about classes. It's about the differences between a `struct` and a [`record struct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#record-struct) (introduced with C# 10 in 2021). As far as I can see it's an original question, that has never been asked before in StackOverflow.

Comment: That is right, I got the wrong understanding of the question

Comment: You might want to consider using `record struct` vs a plain `struct` if performance and memory allocation are concerns; see [this blog post](https://nietras.com/2021/06/14/csharp-10-record-struct/) for more info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer assumes:

- It is known what the [`record` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) does in c#;
- It is known [what a `struct` is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) how it is [different from `class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/choosing-between-class-and-struct);

Then, the decision of using `struct` instead of `record struct` comes down to:

1. You don't **need** the default implementation that `record` bakes in.

   Maybe your struct is so short-lived that it will be used only to pass around structured data; it will be created, consumed and be disposed in very well-known places and you are in total control of their usage. If you are totally, completely sure that you don't need [equality comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs#equality-members), [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) or [string representation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/record-structs#printing-members-printmembers-and-tostring-methods), than you could avoid a few bits of meta-data in your assembly and a few lines of documentation.
2. You don't **want** the default implementation that `record` bakes in.

   This point is kinda weak, considering that you can declare your type as `record struct` and still [provide a custom implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition) of any of the automatic behavior. You can even specify attributes to the auto-properties with the concise syntax. So unless you are planning to provide a custom implementation to most of the automatic ones, you would still benefit from using `record`.
3. You can't use `record struct` because you are locked in a .net version that doesn't support c#10.

   Well, not much to say in this case.

---

In summary, `record struct` is just better in the general case, and honestly it is what `struct` should have been by default since it's inception.

Comment: I don't see downsides to always using a `record struct`, and I like not thinking too much, so I'm just always going to use a `record struct` until I run into issues.

Comment: Agree. And in my opinion, same thought goes for class vs record class.